# Is the below code for selection sort correct?

Tags: sorting

I am taking a course on Data Structures,and the instructor has given this following code for the selection sort.But I think it is not correct because in selection sort,we scan the whole array and find the minimum element in each iteration and swap it with its correct position.But in the code below, we are swapping everytime,we find a element which is smaller than the current element.So please let me know if this is correct or not.

```
public static void selectionsort(int[] listtosort)
{
    for (int i=0; i<listToSort.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j=i+1; j<listToSort.length; j++)
        {
            if (listToSort[i] > listToSort[j])
            {
                swap(listToSort, i, j);
                print(listToSort);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But we always measure the perfomance of the algorithm by its worst case right?Number of swaps will be O(N^2) in the worst case scenario.Also it takes away the fact that selection sort has less number of swaps when compared to insertion sort.

Comment: I mean in the code that I have mentioned,number of swaps will be O(N^2) right in the worst case?

Comment: yeah right they dont change the 'big O' performance But number of swaps become important right if in the memory writes are more expensive than reads like say for example Flash memory?

Comment: So let me get this right.It is safe to assume normal ram and cpu while developing sorting algorithms if the implementation details are not explicitly mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right in that aspect. Instead of swapping each time you encounter with a smaller number, you can store the index of the smaller number and at the end of the inner iteration you can swap the current number with the smallest number. However this approach does not effect the complexity of this sort algorithm. At both it is O (n^2). If a number is smaller swapping it is O(1). If a number is smaller keeping its index is again O(1).

```
public static void SelectionSort ( int [ ] num ) {
 int i, j, first, temp;  
 for ( i = num.length - 1; i > 0; i - - ) {
  first = 0;   //initialize to subscript of first element
  for(j = 1; j <= i; j ++) {
    if( num[ j ] < num[ first ] )         
      first = j;
  }
  temp = num[ first ];   //swap smallest found with element in position i.
  num[ first ] = num[ i ];
  num[ i ] = temp; 
}
```

Comment: Yeah But no.of swaps will increase right.For the code that I have mentioned,the no.of swaps will be O(N^2) in the worst case.So it takes away the one of the advantages of the selection sort that the no.of swaps are less when compared to other sorting algorithms right?

Comment: Selection sort is quite the opposite, it's worst case is essentially it's best case. Have a look at [this link](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) which shows the different complexities. Just google "sorting complexity" and useful information pops up instantly.

Comment: @SaiSankalp That's right, number of swaps will increase most of the time. However that's only a constant multiplier in respect of complexity. (Cost of swapping vs cost of saving index)